# "AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute 'fields'" error when creating and deleting fields in the attribute table using PyQGIS

Tags: pyqgis, attribute-table, fields-attributes, delete, attributeerror

I am currently making a code that will buffer the points then extract vertices and add new coordinates. but I also want to change the `"max depth"` column to `"Height Theo"` and then add another column called `"Height actual"` and the values below it should be equal to the negative (-) value of `"Height Theo"` before exporting this to CSV file.

This is the output of my current script:

[image]

This is the output I want.

[image]

This is my code:

```py
from qgis import processing
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

view = iface.layerTreeView()

selected_nodes = view.selectedNodes()

selected_layers = [node.layer() for node in selected_nodes]

print("merging layers....")
merge = processing.runAndLoadResults("native:mergevectorlayers", {
                                        'LAYERS': selected_layers,
                                        'CRS': QgsCoordinateReferenceSystem('USER:100000'),
                                        'OUTPUT': 'TEMPORARY_OUTPUT'
                                    })

print('Creating Buffer...')
buffer = processing.runAndLoadResults("native:buffer", {
                                        'INPUT': merge['OUTPUT'],
                                        'DISTANCE': 0.18,
                                        'SEGMENTS': 2,
                                        'END_CAP_STYLE': 0,
                                        'JOIN_STYLE': 0,
                                        'MITER_LIMIT': 2,
                                        'DISSOLVE': False,
                                        'OUTPUT': 'TEMPORARY_OUTPUT'
                                    })
 
print('extracting points...')
vertices = processing.runAndLoadResults("native:extractvertices", {
                                            'INPUT': buffer['OUTPUT'],
                                            'OUTPUT': 'TEMPORARY_OUTPUT'
                                        })

print('adding xycoords...')
xycoords = processing.runAndLoadResults("qgis:exportaddgeometrycolumns", {
                                            'INPUT': vertices['OUTPUT'],
                                            'CALC_METHOD': 0,
                                            'OUTPUT': 'TEMPORARY_OUTPUT'
                                        })

dont_delete = ["ID", "X [m]", "Y [m]", "Max. depth [m]"]
all_fields = xycoords.fields().names()
field_ids = [xycoords.fields().indexFromName(f) for f in all_fields if f not in dont_delete]
xycoords.dataProvider().deleteAttributes(field_ids)
xycoords.updateFields()
```

deleting fields does not work

> ```
> # Python Console
> # Use iface to access QGIS API interface or type help(iface) for more info
> # Security warning: typing commands from an untrusted source can harm your computer
> exec(Path('C:/Users/CMCA/OneDrive - Boskalis/Documents/Trial PyQGIS/Creating_Grab.py').read_text())
> merging layers....
> Creating Buffer...
> extracting points...
> adding xycoords...
> Traceback (most recent call last):
>   File "C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS33~1.0\apps\Python39\lib\code.py", line 90, in runcode
>     exec(code, self.locals)
>   File "<input>", line 1, in <module>
>   File "<string>", line 83, in <module>
> AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute 'fields'
> ```

Answer (score 9):

I could get the same error:

> ```
> Traceback (most recent call last):
>   File "C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS32~1.0\apps\Python39\lib\code.py", line 90, in runcode
>     exec(code, self.locals)
>   File "<input>", line 1, in <module>
>   File "<string>", line 10, in <module>
> AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute 'fields'
> ```

`AttributeError` arose due to the output type of the `"qgis:exportaddgeometrycolumns"` algorithm:

```
{'OUTPUT': <QgsVectorLayer: 'Added geom info' (memory)>}
```

As you can see it is a dictionary, however, to achieve field names, one needs to treat the `QgsVectorLayer` only. This can be done by adding the `['OUTPUT']` into your code.

So, please edit your code:

```py
xycoords = processing.runAndLoadResults("qgis:exportaddgeometrycolumns", {
                                            'INPUT': vertices['OUTPUT'],
                                            'CALC_METHOD': 0,
                                            'OUTPUT': 'TEMPORARY_OUTPUT'
                                        })
```

as follows:

```py
xycoords = processing.runAndLoadResults("qgis:exportaddgeometrycolumns", {
                                            'INPUT': vertices['OUTPUT'],
                                            'CALC_METHOD': 0,
                                            'OUTPUT': 'TEMPORARY_OUTPUT'
                                        })['OUTPUT']
```

Then I can easily get field names of the `xycoords` temporary layer with:

```py
all_fields = xycoords.fields().names()
```